# Rails4+Deviseのユーザ情報編集画面のフォームから受け取った値を書き換えて保存したい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Rails4+Deviseでログインできるウェブサービスの練習をしています。

```
rails g devise user
rails g migration add_columns_to_users image
```

により、ユーザ画像のURLを持つimageカラムをuserモデルに追加し

```
rails g devise:views
```

によって生成されたusers#editのテンプレートファイルのform_forの中に

```
<%= f.hidden_field :image %>
```

を追加して、imageカラムの更新をusers#editからできるようにしようとしています。

このとき、input type='hidden'タグのvalueの中身は、
javascriptの他のプログラムによってcanvasのtoDataURL()の内容が入るようになっています。

toDataURL()によって出力されたDataURL文字列をそのままデータベースに保存しても動くとは思うのですが
できれば、サーバ側で受け取ったDataURL文字列をファイルに変換出力して、
そのファイルのURLをimageカラムの情報として持たせたいと思っています。
（現在imageカラムは通常のstring型なのでdata too long for column 'image'...などのエラーもでます）

さきほどまで、users#editから送信されたimageのデータを受け付けることもしてくれなかったのですが
application_controller.rbに

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :image
```

を記述することにより、どうやらデータを受け付けることはできたようです。

しかし、このままだと受け取ったデータをそのままデータベースに受け渡してしまうだけで
受け取ったデータを書き換えることができていません。

DataURL文字列をファイル変換出力しURLを取得するメソッドは出来上がっているので
その関数に、いくつかの情報を渡すだけでURLを取得できるのであと一歩なのですが
ユーザ情報編集画面のフォームから受け取った値を書き換えて保存するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか。

---

追記

現在、以下で教えて頂いた
フォームの要素名を変更してuserモデルにgetterを作成して受け取る方法を試しています。
DataURL文字列をファイル変換出力するメソッドに関しては、その他のControllerなどで
利用することもあるので、Imageモデルのクラスメソッドとして定義しました。
これにより、userモデルのgetterメソッドが呼ばれた時にファイルを保存することが出来たのですが
保存する画像のファイル名にユーザIDを利用したく‌​て、userモデルのgetterからcurrent_userにアクセスしてみたところcurrent_userの値にアクセスできないという問題に突き当たっています。
userモデルにgetterを作成する方法も発想として無かったのですごくためになっているのですが
やはりcontr‌​ollerにコードを書いてuserモデルに渡してあげるべきなのではないかと悩んでいます。

users#editから送信されたデータがDeviseのControllerのどの部分に届くのか、さっぱりわからないのですが（そもそもControllerが存在しない？rails generateで作成するのかな？）Controllerベースでの実装方法がわかる方いらっしゃいましたら是非教えていただけないでしょうか。
（私の考え方が根本的に間違っている場合は、そこを指摘していただきたいです。）

Comment: deviseのタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず、カラムとフォームのフィールド名が一緒だと都合が悪いので、別のものに変更してください。ここではフィールド名を`:image_data`にしたとして説明します。

```ruby
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  def image_data=(data)
    self.image = save_file(data)
  end

  def image_data #画像の読み込み
    open(self.image).read
  end

  private 
  def save_file(data)
    #すでにあるというファイルを保存するメソッド
    return url
  end
end
```

ただし、これだとimage_dataにデータを渡したタイミング(@users.image_data = dataしたタイミング)で保存が走ります。あまり頻繁に保存するのが都合が悪ければafter_saveあたりのコールバックで保存するようにしてください。

---

「画像をファイルに保存するメソッドをどこに定義すべきか」ですが、少なくともコントローラではありません。`User`の`id`を使用したいのであれば、

- Userモデルのインスタンスメソッドとして実装する。この場合、`self.id`で参照できます。
- 別クラスに実装し、Userモデルからそれを呼び出す時にパラメータとして`self.id`を渡す

などという方法があります(他にもいろいろありますが)

そのメソッドがどれだけの分量かわかりませんが、単純なメソッドならUserモデルのインスタンスメソッドとして定義してしまう(上記例のsave_fileメソッドにそのロジックを実装する)のが簡単です。

`current_user`は、「現在ログインしているユーザー」という文脈でのみ使用すべきです。たとえば、ファイル名にidを使用したいという場合に用いるidは「現在ログインしているユーザー」ではなく「その画像に紐付くユーザー」のはずです。

Comment: なるほど、単純にusersモデルにsetterを追加するだけで良かったんですね。難しく考えすぎてました。

Comment: save_fileメソッドはApplicationControllerに定義されているので、できればControllerを拡張（この場合DeviseのControllerになるのかな？）する形で実装したいと考えているのですが、そのようなことはできないでしょうか。

Comment: 先ほどのコメントですが、訂正させてください。いろいろと試行錯誤していたら、save_fileはcontrollerではなくmodelで定義すべき関数のような気がしてきました。

Comment: Imageモデルのクラスメソッドとして定義することで、save_fileメソッドの呼び出しには成功したのですが、保存する画像のファイル名にユーザIDを利用したくてcurrent_userにアクセスしてみたのですが、current_userの値はcontrollerからしか取得出来ないようでした。やはり、根本的にcontrollerにコードを書いてuserモデルに渡してあげるべきなのではと悩んでいます。

Comment: 盲点でした！Userモデルのメソッドをいじっていたはずなのに気が付きませんでした。self.idで普通にアクセスできますよね！モデルとコントローラを混合して混乱していたようです。とても助かりました！！